# How to get the text of a contenteditable span?

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

I have a form in my twig template that contains a contenteditable span. I want to get get the new text changed and append it to the span, so when the form is submited it contains the new text.

Here is my html form :

```
<form action="{{ path('change') }}" method="post">
    <span name="profil" class="profil" contenteditable="true">{{ prof.libel }}</span>
    <button name="change" type="submit">
    </button>
</form>
```

This is my jQuery script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('span.profil').change(function () {
            $text = $(this).text();
            $(this).append(document.createTextNode($text));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you aware that your HTML is invalid? Your opening button element is missing a closing angle bracket

Comment: ah ok that's  because I deleted some code when I posted this question. But in my project my code isn't missing anything.

Answer (score 1):

The SPAN element has no such `change` event. You should capture the text of the span in the `click` event of the BUTTON, or in the `submit` event of the FORM, e.g.

```
$('#theForm').on("submit", function() {
    var text = $('span.profil').text();
    // or  $('span.profil')[0].innerHTML;
});

// or...
$('#theButton').on("click", function() {
    var text = $('span.profil').text();
});
```

**Ref**: The [`div`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-div-element), [`span`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-span-element), and others implements the **[`HTMLElement`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#htmlelement)** interface which doesn't have an interaction for the `change` event. Check the elements wich support handling  the [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change).

Comment: if I change the span to div will it work??? because I saw many div examples

Comment: The [`div`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-div-element), [`span`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-span-element), and others implements the **[`HTMLElement`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#htmlelement)** interface which doesn't have an interaction for the `change` event. Check the elements wich support handling  the [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

Comment: I think this won't work in my case, because I have dynamically created buttons and span elements , so how can I identify which span and which button to work with???